# Best way to do paging in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitableview

I'm working on a real estate app. The app query a datafeed server after user fill in a form (min rooms, price and so on) and it gets a json string with specific key/value pairs (property name,property address,longitude/latitude,price,etc...).

What I'm trying to do is allowing the user to browse the listing in a UITableView even if the feed contains a long list of items without having to overload the user iphone (the returned items count is not known before the query is done, so the app need to handle this)...What would you suggest me for paging ?

Thx in advance,

Stephane

Comment: best implementation I found on paging: http://www.lwxted.com/blog/2012/smart-data-loading-table-views/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is written correctly using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` (and you don't use `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, or it is very fast), UITableView should be able to handle thousands of rows without overloading the device. You just need to be concerned with the storage of your raw data.

As for your problem of not knowing the number of rows until the query is complete, that is easy enough to work around. As you receive more rows from the query, just use UITableView's `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to inform the table view that more rows are available (and be sure that your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will then reflect these new rows).

If you are also wanting to wait until the user scrolls to the end of the current list before continuing the query, note that UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView and UITableViewDelegate implements UIScrollViewDelegate. So just use `scrollViewDidScroll:` on your UITableViewDelegate to know when the user scrolls and then check the table view's `contentOffset` to determine if they've scrolled down far enough that you want to load more data.

Answer (score 0):

whats the average number of items people can have? 10, 100, 1000? Does it have images or just data? Generally, I'd vote for not having any pagination - just load more as you scroll down, and try to load all of them at the very  first time if there are not too many. You can also cache them on the device and add "pull to refresh" functionality, this way you improve offline  experience.

Comment: 10 items per page if it was on a webpage and it has images to display in the table cells

Comment: As said I don't know the total listing in advance. For example, a particular search could have 110 items, showing 10 items per "page" it makes 11 "page" to show

Comment: 10 items per page if it was on a webpage and it has images to display in the table cells

Comment: In that case I would just load everything in one table, and with no pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Well if some one is interested in paging using buttons then I found this post usefull http://www.mindyourcode.com/ios/iphone/pagination-in-uitableview-with-next-previous-buttons/
may be for some others it would be helpful